# How to sort an associative array in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table i.e

```
id | a | b | c | d |ud_id
 1 | 20| 8 | 45| 18| 1
```

Now I want to retrieve that data in php sort the array and find the highest field in this example (c=45)

```
$query="SELECT `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` from table where ud_id=1";
$rs=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

But how can I sort this associative array and find the highest key?

Comment: it seems your database design is wrong. you have to find that highest using SQL, not PHP

Comment: Agreed with Col. Shrapnel, table design isn't suited for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a whole bunch of sorting functions.

The one is sounds like you want is [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

See the PHP manual for the other alternatives such as `sort()`, `ksort()`, `natsort()`, `usort()`, and a number of other variations. There's also `shuffle()` to sort randomly.

[EDIT]
Okay, step-by-step to get the highest value out of the array:

```
asort($row);  //or arsort() for reverse order, if you prefer.
end($row);  //positions the array pointer to the last element.
print current($row); //prints "45" because it's the sorted highest value.
print key($row); //prints "c" because it's the key of the hightst sorted value.
```

There are a whole bunch of other ways to do it as well.

Comment: when i used `print_r(sort($row));` this give me the result 1 and i want the hight key value like `['c']=>45`

Comment: @source: okay, so what if you try `asort()` as I suggested?

Comment: okay i use `asort($row); print_r($row)` and the result is `Array ( [1] => 8 [b] => 8 [3] => 18 [d] => 18 [0] => 20 [a] => 20 [2] => 45 [c] => 45 )` then how can i get the highest value from this array.

Comment: @source: see my edits for one way to do it. But there's any number of other ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just like @Spudley said, `arsort` is the answer. You can get the first key of the resulting array by getting the first of its `array_keys`.

```
// ...
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($rs);
arsort ($row);
$keys = array_keys ($row);
printf ("key: %s, value: %s", $keys[0], $row[$keys[0]]);
```

Also note `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: but `asort` sort the array in ascending order and want to sort it in descending order so that on the first offset there should be the highest value.

Comment: @source - if you **read the manual** pages that I linked you to, you'll see that `asort()` has a matching function `arsort()` to do the same sort in reverse order.

Comment: @Spudley my desired function was `arsort()` not `asort()` any way thank u v much