# How to sort associative array

Tags: php, arrays, ksort

I want to sort the key of the following array. I use ksort(), but i don't know how to use it. Any idea?

```
<?php
        $a = array(
                'kuy' => 'kuy',
                'apple' => 'apple',
                'thida' => 'thida',
                'vanna' => 'vanna',
                'ravy' => 'ravy'
              );

        $b = ksort($a);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($b);
        echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Maybe `ksort` is not the right function. It depends on what you want to sort. [Here is a list of all sort functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). To learn how to use a function, **have a look at its documentation**, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: so what does print_r($b) show you? Have you read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php? It is hard to be any clearer really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sort an associative array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497482/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) sorts the array itself and does not create a sorted copy

```
$a = array(
  'kuy'   => 'kuy',
  'apple' => 'apple',
  'thida' => 'thida',
  'vanna' => 'vanna',
  'ravy'  => 'ravy'
);

ksort($a);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

ksort does not return an array. It just sorts the original array, and returns bool "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. "

So your sorted array is $a, not $b.
see it here  :
http://codepad.org/zMTFTPGf

Comment: @KingCrunch, apologies for incorrect language, what I meant was it does not return an array.

Comment: Independent from what you meant, its wrong ;) You should fix your answer

Answer (score 2):

You find your answer there: http://php.net/manual/de/function.ksort.php

Use it just like:

```
ksort($a);
```

then $a is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to preserve the original order of $a then use :-

```
ksort($a);
print_r($a);
```

If you want to keep $a, but also want a sorted version use:-

```
$b = $a;
ksort($b);
print_r($b);
```

As  said in my comment the manual page makes it quite clear.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 1):

[**ksort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) returns boolean value and sort the original array so you should print `$a` instead of `$b` because `$b` is a boolean value returned by the ksort which is either true or false depending on the result of ksort

```
ksort($a);    
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort) returns a boolean - whether the sort succeeded or not. It sorts the array in-place - where it changes the array variable rather than returns a sorted copy.

Try:

```
ksort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ksort` takes its argument by reference and modifies it directly, the return value just indicates syccess or failure.

Answer (score 0):

ksort returns a boolean on whether it was successful or not, it doesn't return another sorted array.  It changes the original array.

```
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Felix said look at the documentation. you can also look at the example [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/sorting_array.php#associative)